# IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Tags: python, biosppy

I'm using ipython notebook and biosppy 0.1.2 for analyzing EDA data. I get the following IndexError:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-0191d6af629b> in <module>()
     37         eda_final = eda_real_list
     38 
---> 39         out = EDA.eda(signal=eda_in_time_ok, sampling_rate=100.0,   show=True)
     40 
     41 

C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\biosppy\signals\eda.pyc in eda(signal, sampling_rate, show)
     89                           amplitudes=amps,
     90                           path=None,
---> 91                           show=True)
     92 
     93     # output

C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\biosppy\plotting.py in plot_eda(ts, raw, filtered, onsets, peaks, amplitudes, path, show)
    351     ax2.plot(ts, filtered, linewidth=MAJOR_LW, label='Filtered')
    352 
--> 353     ax2.vlines(ts[onsets], ymin, ymax,
    354                color='m',
    355                linewidth=MINOR_LW,

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

this is my simple code:

```
from biosppy.signals import eda as EDA

for pict in blocks_images:

    picture = imread('C:\Users\Roberta\Desktop\Arousal-Valence_setup-last\\'+pict)


    for subj in range(0,len(blocks[pict]['ecg'])):

        time_start=5   # time in seconds of image onset
        time_stop=35   # time in seconds of image off


        eda_data = blocks[pict]['eda'][subj]

        time_eda_1 = [eda[0] for eda in eda_data]
        time_eda = np.array(time_eda_1)-time_eda_1[0]
        index_start = map(int,list(time_eda)).index(time_start)
        index_stop = map(int,list(time_eda)).index(time_stop)


        eda_in_time_ok = map(float, [ii[1] for ii in eda_data[index_start:index_stop]if ii[1] != 0.0])

        out = EDA.eda(signal=eda_in_time_ok, sampling_rate=100.0, show=True)
```

I try to solve it follow other post I found here withouth any positive results.
Can someone expain me what is the problem and how can I fix it?
Unfortunately I'm quite new in programming and I did not find a lot of documentation on bioSPPy that can help me.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`EDA.eda()` is expecting an np.array not a python list.

Add `import numpy as np`, and change the line

```
eda_in_time_ok = map(float, [ii[1] for ii in eda_data[index_start:index_stop]if ii[1] != 0.0])
```

to this

```
eda_in_time_ok = np.array([float(ii[1]) for ii in eda_data[index_start:index_stop] if ii[1] != 0.0])
```

Comment: Thanks RooTwo! Unfortunately I had already tried! Nothing change! I get the same error: